# Using `overlap`, `kernel time` and `utilization` to optimize one's kernels

Tags: optimization, profiling, cuda

My kernel archive 100% utilization, but the `kernel time` is at only 3% and there is `no time overlap between memory copies and kernels`.

Especially the high utilization and the low kernel time don't make sense to me.

So how should I proceed in optimizing my kernel?

I already made sure, that I only have coalesced and pinned memory access, like the profiler recommended.

```
`Quadro FX 580 utilization = 100.00% (62117.00/62117.00)`

Kernel time = 3.05 % of total GPU time 
Memory copy time = 0.9 % of total GPU time
Kernel taking maximum time = Pinned (0.7% of total GPU time)
Memory copy taking maximum time = memcpyHtoD (0.5% of total GPU time)
There is no time overlap between memory copies and kernels on GPU
```

Furtermore I have no warp serialization, no divergent branches, and no occupancy limiting factor.

```
Kernel details: Grid size: [4 1 1], Block size: [256 1 1]
Register Ratio: 0.9375 ( 7680 / 8192 ) [10 registers per thread]
Shared Memory Ratio: 0.09375 ( 1536 / 16384 ) [60 bytes per Block]
Active Blocks per SM: 3 (Maximum Active Blocks per SM: 8)
Active threads per SM: 768 (Maximum Active threads per SM: 768)
Potential Occupancy: 1 ( 24 / 24 )
Achieved occupancy: 0.333333 (on 4 SMs)
Occupancy limiting factor: None
```

p.s. I don't claim that I wrote wundercode, but I just don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: As far as I know, "GPU time" is time of existance of GPU context (which is usually your application total execution time), and not time of actual GPU usage, so 96% of time your GPU does nothing.

Comment: @aland But my there are no limiting factors. Does this mean, it is waiting for memory all the time even though I used pinned and coalesced memory access?

Comment: As far as I understand, the GPU is just stalling. `Kernel time` is time between kernel launch and all threads of kernel finishing, `Memory copy time` is the execution time of `cudaMemcpy` & co (CPU<->GPU data transfer, affected by pinned memory usage). The timing of in-kernel calls (affected by coalesced memory access) could be seen in detailed statistics for each kernel, and are not shown in output you've presented. So actually, CPU code takes 96% of time, and GPU-related part takes only 4%.

Comment: Okay, I removed a lot of error checking code on the CPU and the `Kernel time` raised to 33%. So I only need to be concerned about `kernel time`/`Memory copy time`?

Answer (score 1):

it seems the grid size of your kernel is too small to make full use of SM.
why not decrease block size and increase the grid size.
i think it will do some help.