# How to find out if kernel is memory bound or computation bound?

Tags: cuda

I think my kernel is memory bound (because most GPGPU code is memory bound), but I don't actually know for sure. How can I found it out for myself. Probably one has to use the visual profiler, as it depends on the used GPU.

If it is explained in the CUDA Programming guide or in other NVIDIA documentation, don't hesitate to just post a link with a page number, so I can read it up for myself.

**Clarification**

I would prefer are general "rule" how to determine the limiting factor, but in my special case you can find details about my kernel here: [Using `overlap`, `kernel time` and `utilization` to optimize one's kernels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839428/using-overlap-kernel-time-and-utilization-to-optimize-ones-kernels)

Comment: Have you checked your kernel launch configuration and properties against the CUDA occupancy calculator? Definitely try that. Then, profiling is also a good idea. Source code analysis can also be useful... what is your arithmetic intensity? Are your global memory accesses coalesced? Etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [presentation](https://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/sc_2010/CUDA_Tutorial/SC10_Analysis_Driven_Optimization.pdf) from NVIDIA talks about selectively disabling memory accesses and arithmetic in your kernel by modifying your source code, in order to determine if one of them is limiting your performance.

Answer (score 1):

A nice trick without any source code modification can be used for code compiled with compute capability 2.0 and above ( based on [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451156/cuda-compute-capability-1-0-faster-than-3-5/) )

using the "--use_fast_math" flag one can easily increase\decrease compute pressure.

- if setting this flag gives a large speed-up, this would indicate a compute bound kernel.
- if setting this flag gives little to no speed-up, this would indicate a balanced\memory bound kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I though I would pitch in an answer even though there is an accepted answer and this question is old.

I had a similar problem in my code, although at the time I didn't know it.
I ran the Nvidia Visual Profiler (`nvvp`) and analysed my program. I found that the profiler had detected my program was limited in some fashion and had some recommendations.

A great tool to use if you are unsure on where to begin.